# extension of "subharmonic" function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $f$ be a $C^2-$function on an open set $\omega\subset R^n$ such that : $f\times \Delta f \ge 0$ on $\omega.$ I am wondering about the existence of a $C^2-$extension $F$ of $f$ in $\Omega \supset \omega$ such that $f\times \Delta f \ge 0$ on $\Omega$.

NB. $C^2$ can be replaced with the Sobolev space $H^2$.

Thanks

Comment: Cf. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184456/a-special-extension-of-a-two-variable-function and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184533/two-variable-functions-with-positive-laplacian over at MSE

Answer (score 1):

No extension is possible unless some additional conditions are imposed.
A positive subharmonic function in the unit disc in the plane can tend to infinity
at the boundary and certainly has no extension to a twice larger disc.

Comment: conditions such as $\omega$ is bounded and $f$ is continuous in $\overline{\omega}?$

Comment: At the very least you need to assume $C^2$ on the boundary as well, since there are subharmonic, indeed harmonic, functions with continuous nondifferentiable boundaries.

Comment: For my question, I can take $\omega$ smooth enough. 